# Crash on iPad 2 - Unity3D / iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an app that's already existing. This app works fine on an iPad Pro / iOS 10. I'm trying to get it to work on iPad2 / iOS 9.3.5.

I manage to build it with XCODE. I can play it well. BUT, when I load a specific scene, it crashes. 
XCODE just displays "iPad was disconnected". The last Debug shows :

"Unloading 3 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)"

No warnings, no errors.

After many researches I figured this was a memory limit issue. So I proceeded to empty the scene piece by piece to figure what's causing the issue.

The scene is now empty (^^) and it still crashes. Below is the profiler memory for the empty scene.

[image: Memory profiler]

Crash log :

```
Incident Identifier: A8EAA62E-F1BE-4969-A9DE-8095A41F685A
CrashReporter Key:   1a06f0ff4da2846aaf101b885d553b22478f0f3a
Hardware Model:      iPad2,4
Process:             mediaserverd [361]
Path:                /usr/sbin/mediaserverd
Identifier:          mediaserverd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2017-01-10 17:08:24.24 +0100
Launch Time:         2017-01-10 12:14:35.35 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x815dba57
Triggered by Thread:  12

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21766920 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x2181b3a4 _os_semaphore_wait + 12
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x21668d4a _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 370
3   CoreMedia                       0x23af2152 cmsmApplicationStateChangedNotificationCallback + 78
4   CoreFoundation                  0x21a03902 __CFNotificationCenterAddObserver_block_invoke + 126
5   CoreFoundation                  0x21aa1734 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
6   CoreFoundation                  0x21aa113e _CFXRegistrationPost + 390
7   CoreFoundation                  0x21aa0f1c ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 40
8   CoreFoundation                  0x21af7c6a -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1334
9   CoreFoundation                  0x21a01082 _CFXNotificationPost + 486
10  Foundation                      0x222425de -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 74
11  SpringBoardServices             0x231b93be __SBApplicationStateBeginGeneratingChangeNotifications_block_invoke_2 + 78
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x2165d822 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x2165d80e _dispatch_client_callout + 22
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x2166bba8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1524
15  CoreFoundation                  0x21ab1b6c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
16  CoreFoundation                  0x21ab0066 __CFRunLoopRun + 1574
17  CoreFoundation                  0x219ff228 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
18  CoreFoundation                  0x219ff014 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
19  mediaserverd                    0x00059f9e 0x58000 + 8094
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x216a7872 start + 2

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2177c2f8 kevent_qos + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x21671d60 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 256
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x21671abe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 38

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x217668d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x217666d4 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x21ab1ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x21aafe4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4   CoreFoundation                  0x219ff228 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x21a3fdd2 CFRunLoopRun + 98
6   VirtualAudio                    0x01e3fee4 0x1e38000 + 32484
7   VirtualAudio                    0x01e3fdba 0x1e38000 + 32186
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2182385a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x218237ce _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821724 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coremedia.remakerserver
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x217668d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x217666d4 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x21ab1ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x21aafe4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4   CoreFoundation                  0x219ff228 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x21a3fdd2 CFRunLoopRun + 98
6   MediaToolbox                    0x26f45644 figRemakerFamilyServerThread + 256
7   CoreMedia                       0x23aa79b8 figThreadMain + 208
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2182385a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x218237ce _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821724 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.coremedia.recorderserver
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x217668d0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x217666d4 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x21ab1ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x21aafe4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4   CoreFoundation                  0x219ff228 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x21a3fdd2 CFRunLoopRun + 98
6   Celestial                       0x271d43c2 figRecorderServerThread + 794
7   CoreMedia                       0x23aa79b8 figThreadMain + 208
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2182385a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x218237ce _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821724 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:  audio IO: VAD [vdef] Aggregate Device UID 1
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2177a998 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21822e26 _pthread_cond_wait + 594
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21822bd0 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 16
3   CoreAudio                       0x23a38da4 HALB_Guard::WaitFor(unsigned long long) + 92
4   CoreAudio                       0x239c9dea HALS_IOContext::IOWorkLoop_SleepUntilWakeTime(unsigned long long) + 142
5   CoreAudio                       0x239ca9c0 HALS_IOContext::IOWorkLoop() + 3000
6   CoreAudio                       0x239c60b4 HALS_IOContext::IOThreadEntry(void*) + 424
7   CoreAudio                       0x239c5ec6 ___ZN14HALS_IOContextC2EP11HALS_SystemP11HALS_ClientNS0_10PowerStateE_block_invoke + 82
8   CoreAudio                       0x239daa8c HALB_IOThread::Entry(void*) + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2182385a _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x218237ce _pthread_start + 110
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821724 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21766938 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166e90a _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 126
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166df98 _dispatch_worker_thread + 116
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2182385a _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x218237ce _pthread_start + 110
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821724 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21766938 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166e90a _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 126
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166df98 _dispatch_worker_thread + 116
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2182385a _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x218237ce _pthread_start + 110
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821724 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: AudioControl
Thread 8:
0   CoreMedia                       0x23ae70e8 cmsUpdateMuteStatus + 0
1   CoreMedia                       0x23ae629e cmsSetIsPlaying + 134
2   CoreMedia                       0x23af1df6 __cmsFinalize_block_invoke + 54
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x21668df4 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 540
4   CoreMedia                       0x23af1c82 cmsFinalize + 78
5   CoreFoundation                  0x219fb794 CFRelease + 424
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x2165d822 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166c5e8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1560
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166bfcc _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 96
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821b28 _pthread_wqthread + 1024
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2177b864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x21766938 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166e90a _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 126
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166df98 _dispatch_worker_thread + 116
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2182385a _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x218237ce _pthread_start + 110
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821724 thread_start + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2177b864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 12 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.assertiond.processassertionconnection
Thread 12 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x21297a66 objc_msgSend + 6
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x2165d822 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166a422 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1758
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x21669a60 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 284
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166c15c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x2166bfcc _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 96
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821b28 _pthread_wqthread + 1024
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x2177b864 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821b34 _pthread_wqthread + 1036
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21821718 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 12 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x15d7ec50    r1: 0x2314770f      r2: 0x1f4210b0      r3: 0x15eb9630
    r4: 0x15eb9630    r5: 0x002011e0      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x1f420ee8
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x815dba4b     r10: 0x00201180     r11: 0x15e7be30
    ip: 0xfe151ea5    sp: 0x1f420ee4      lr: 0x2165d823      pc: 0x21297a66
  cpsr: 0x40000030

Binary Images:
```

[...]

```
Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed while requesting activity/breadcrumb diagnostics
```

Thank you for reading me,
q

Comment: may be you are using bigger image, 2048x2048, in iPad 2 it will crash and in iPad Pro it runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I downsized all the images so I dont think this is it but will definitely double check.

Comment: in Activity monitor check how much virtual memory loaded. Here is maximum limitation for all device https://app.box.com/s/33x7gftlbdglrvmukg5m2fthxrvbzwko

Comment: Thank you for this useful doc ! Getting back to you

Comment: Apple Officially stoped support for iPad 2. So you can ignore iPad 2 also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you Guru for your time,

It was indeed, memory related. I was loading a lot of GameObjects. A lot of these GameObjects were inactive so I thought they weren't taking a lot of memory. 
I was wrong. 
Rather than SetActive() methods, I now use the Instantiate, Destroy methods.